pandas not discoverable for different users on the same computer
I want to share my code with other users on a single computer to ensure a backup of automated procedures.
The python files are all there and everything appears to be in order, but when a secondary person logs on to the computer, they cannot import pandas. I am unsure if there are other modules failing, but I am stumped at pandas for the moment.
I created a script which tries to identify firstly, whether it can import pandas and secondly where sys.path are so I can endeavour to solve the issue.
Here is that script:
import pandas 

try:
    print(pandas.__version__)
    print(pandas.__file__)
    print(pandas.__package__)
except:
    print('Cannot see suitable pandas')

import sys

print('Let us determine where the modules are stored')
for path in sys.path:
    print(path)

My computer returns:

And my colleagues computer returns:

Any thoughts as to why this is occurring?

I guess, its  python installation issue. Python is only installed for 1 user (you) and is not accessible for other users.  You can try creating a new virtual environment in a directory which is accessible for all users on the PC and install pandas in it.

Quite strange that import pandas doesn't raise an exception in this session. That said, this is not really a programming question. You might want to ask on superuser
